# c++: PThread Scheduling vs. Windows Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have some experience with windows threads and am looking into pthreads. I've a question about the pthread scheduling. On windows you can set the Process-Priority and within a Process you can set the process-Priority. The Windows Scheduler executes always the process with the highest Process-Priority, and in the Process the Threads on a Round-Robin.

Now to the pthreads you can set the scheduler-policy via sched_setscheduler, and set priority for real-time-modi. Everything, wright so far?

QUESTIONS:

1) How are pthreads scheduled over different processes?

2) Are real-time-threads performed before threads with lower priority or is there a round-robin?

3) How can i get as much realtime-behavior (f.e. for i/o -signals) as possible and how much can i get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to realise that POSIX threads (pthreads) are specified in a standard that imposes certain minimum requirements on implementations, but also allows them considerable leeway.

pthreads has a concept of [*Thread Scheduling Contention Scope*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_04_02).  pthreads implementations must support at least one of `PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM` and `PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS` scheduling contention scopes.

If a thread is scheduled under the `PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM` contention scope, it competes equally to be scheduled with all other processes and threads using `PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM` on the system.

If a thread is scheduled under the `PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS` contention scope, it only directly competes with other threads also using `PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS` in the same process.  How that group of threads is then scheduled with respect to other processes / threads is unspecified by POSIX, but typically each group of threads using `PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS` in the same process is treated as a single `PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM` entity.

It is common for implementations to only support one of these - for example, Linux supports only the `PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM` scheduling contention scope.

Under pthreads, runnable higher priority threads always execute in preference to lower priority threads.  With threads at the same priority level, if a thread is using the `SCHED_FIFO` scheduling policy then it will continue to run until it blocks or yields; if it is using the `SCHED_RR` scheduling policy then it will also be pre-empted after using up its time quantum.

I do not believe POSIX imposes any constraints on realtime performance - after all, realtime latency is strongly influenced by the underlying hardware.  Apart from setting a realtime scheduling policy (`SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`), you can also get more deterministic latency by locking your process memory using `mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE);` and pre-faulting in the memory you require.